# Ошибка: "Error: unknown column 'Длжн'" при выполнении group_by (dplyr 0.4.3)

Tags: r

Имеется файл "Test.txt" в кодировке CP1251

```
ФИО|Должность|Значение
Иванов И.И.|старший специалист(190000200707)|5
Иванов И.И.|старший специалист(190000200707)|3
Иванов И.И.|старший специалист(190000200707)|2
Иванов И.И.|старший специалист(190000200707)|3
Петров П.П.|специалист 1 разряда(190000200710)|2
Петров П.П.|специалист 1 разряда(190000200710)|2
Петров П.П.|специалист 1 разряда(190000200710)|4
Петров П.П.|специалист 1 разряда(190000200710)|4
```

Выполняю следующий код:
    library (dplyr)
    library (stringr)

```
file <- file <- "Test.txt"
df_temp <- read.csv(file, head=TRUE, sep="|", dec=",")
df_temp1 <- mutate(df_temp, Длжн = str_sub (Должность, 1, str_length(Должность)-14))
df_gr1 <- group_by(df_temp1, ФИО, Длжн)
df_sm1 <- summarise (df_gr1, СуммаЗначение = sum(Значение))
```

На строке

```
df_gr1 <- group_by(df_temp1, ФИО, Длжн)
```

Выдается ошибка:

```
Error: unknown column 'Длжн'
```

**Вопрос:** на рабочей станции под Win 7 вышеприведенный фрагмент успешно работает, а под Win10 выдает ошибку. В чем может быть причина. 
**Версии** dplyr, rstudio, r под Win 7 и Win 10 одинаковые.

PS.
Если вместо имени 'Длжн' использовать латинские 'Dlgn, то код успешно отрабатывает на рабочей станции Win 10.

**Результаты работы под Win10**

```
>df_temp
            ФИО                          Должность Значение
1   Иванов И.И.   старший специалист(190000200707)        1
2   Иванов И.И.   старший специалист(190000200707)        3
3   Иванов И.И.   старший специалист(190000200707)        3
....
133 Петров П.П. специалист 1 разряда(190000200710)        4

> df_temp1
            ФИО                          Должность Значение                 Длжн
1   Иванов И.И.   старший специалист(190000200707)        1   старший специалист
2   Иванов И.И.   старший специалист(190000200707)        3   старший специалист
3   Иванов И.И.   старший специалист(190000200707)        3   старший специалист
...
133 Петров П.П. специалист 1 разряда(190000200710)        4 специалист 1 разряда
```

Comment: Очевидно, проблема с кодировкой на Windows 10. Решение проблемы может быть как в настройках RStudio, так и в настройках ОС.

Comment: Регулярно сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой в dplyr. Проще всего, имхо, переименовать колонки латиницей.

Comment: Конечно проще сразу на латинице писать, но:
1. сам факт не дает успокоится т.к. с точки зрения версий, настроек R, RStudio и пакетов с Win явных расхождений не видно;
2. добивает факт дуализм наименования колонок в наборе: 
те которые изначально в структурированном файле - кириллицей, 
а те которые порождаем - латиницей.
3. для удобства демонстрации результатов для клиентов придется латиницу конвертировать в кириллицу;

Comment: Покажите вывод переменной `df_temp`.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov в описании приложил выводы переменных df_temp b df_temp1. 
Имею рабочий пример кода с файлом данных. Если требуется, каким образом поделиться